# How to process huge text files that contain EOF / Ctrl-Z characters using Python on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, text, sed, eof

I have a number of large comma-delimited text files (the biggest is about 15GB) that I need to process using a Python script.  The problem is that the files sporadically contain DOS EOF (Ctrl-Z) characters in the middle of them.  (Don't ask me why, I didn't generate them.)  The other problem is that the files are on a Windows machine.

On Windows, when my script encounters one of these characters, it assumes it is at the end of the file and stops processing.  For various reasons, I am not allowed to copy the files to any other machine.  But I still need to process them.

Here are my ideas so far:

1. Read the file in binary mode, throwing out bytes that equal `chr(26)`.  This would work, but it would take approximately forever.
2. Use something like `sed` to eliminate the EOF characters. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, `sed` on Windows has the same problem and will quit when it sees the EOF.
3. Use some kind of `Notepad` program and do a find-and-replace.  But it turns out that `Notepad`-type programs don't cope well with 15GB files.

My IDEAL solution would be some way to just read the file *as text* and simply ignore the Ctrl-Z characters.  Is there a reasonable way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you looked at running `sed` under a pseudo-Unix environment like Cygwin? It was built for exactly this purpose, and I've got to image there's a way around EOF characters...

Comment: It's not Python that treats Ctrl+Z as EOF in text files:  that's deep in the bowels of the Windows file system.  It's impossible on Windows, in any programming language, to open a file in text mode and *not* have Ctrl+Z treated as end-of-file.

Comment: @TimPeters, I don't think that's true - I dare you to find a binary/text flag in the Windows API [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx). It's just that the conventions are so pervasive that it's hard to bypass them.

Comment: @MarkRansom, you could well be right! I never use the Windows API directly except when writing Windows-specific code for the Python implementation, so know as little about it as possible ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's  easy to use Python to delete the DOS EOF chars; for example,

```
def delete_eof(fin, fout):
    BUFSIZE = 2**15
    EOFCHAR = chr(26)
    data = fin.read(BUFSIZE)
    while data:
        fout.write(data.translate(None, EOFCHAR))
        data = fin.read(BUFSIZE)

import sys
ipath = sys.argv[1]
opath = ipath + ".new"
with open(ipath, "rb") as fin, open(opath, "wb") as fout:
    delete_eof(fin, fout)
```

That takes a file path as its first argument, and copies the file but without `chr(26)` bytes to the same file path with `.new` appended.  Fiddle to taste.

By the way, are you *sure* that DOS EOF characters are your only problem?  It's hard to conceive of a sane way in which they could end up in files *intended* to be treated as text files.

Comment: At this point in the project I am wary of assuming any sort of *intent* on the part of the people who provided the files.  :P

This definitely isn't my only problem, but it definitely is my *biggest* problem.