# Why Python does not see all the rows in a file?

Tags: python, input, line-breaks

I count number of rows (lines) in a file using Python in the following method:

```
n = 0
for line in file('input.txt'):
   n += 1
print n
```

I run this script under Windows.

Then I count the number of rows in the same file using Unix command:

```
wc -l input.txt
```

Counting with Unix command gives a significantly larger number of rows.

So, my question is: Why Python does not see all the rows in the file? Or is it a question of definition?

Comment: Perhaps your file contains EOF markers? Those are a real pain on Windows.

Comment: See [How to process huge text files that contain EOF / Ctrl-Z characters using Python on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20695336)

Comment: Strange... Never seen this before.

Comment: Can you verify which is correct? Python or the unix command? Careful that you did not use a capital L I.E. `wc -L <file>`, which gives the length of the longest line, not the number of lines (which could make sense if it's significantly larger)

Comment: `wc` seems to be correct (if I judge by the file size). I use small l. So, it is really number of rows.

Comment: Then open the file in binary mode (and count newline characters as you read blocks) or use `import io; for line in io.open('input.txt'):` which I strongly suspect is not going to fall for EOF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have a file with one or more DOS EOF (CTRL-Z) characters in it, ASCII codepoint 0x1A. When Windows opens a file in text mode, it'll still honour the old DOS semantics and *end* a file whenever it reads that character. See [Line reading chokes on 0x1A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405058/line-reading-chokes-on-0x1a).

Only by opening a file in binary mode can you bypass this behaviour. To do so and still count lines, you have two options:

- read in chunks, then count the number of line separators in each chunk:

  ```
  def bufcount(filename, linesep=os.linesep, buf_size=2 ** 15):
      lines = 0
      with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
          last = ''
          for buf in iter(f.read, ''):
              lines += buf.count(linesep)
              if last and last + buf[0] == linesep:
                  # count line separators straddling a boundary
                  lines += 1
              if len(linesep) > 1:
                  last = buf[-1]
      return lines
  ```

  Take into account that on Windows `os.linesep` is set to `\r\n`, adjust as needed for your file; in binary mode line separators are not translated to `\n`.
- Use [`io.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open); the `io` set of file objects open the file in binary mode always, then do the translations themselves:

  ```
  import io

  with io.open(filename) as f:
      lines = sum(1 for line in f)
  ```